# Android, how to improve performance on a network area with sockets?

Tags: java, android, performance, sockets

I'm developing a real time game to learn Android. I'm using Tomcat and Webservices to exchange some data when the game starts. I'm using sockets. Both Android devices can exchange information through sockets with a Java process - which could be my server. Sometimes they have to send information and sometimes they are getting information from the server.

I have checked using WiFi and 3G. My surprise is how slow 3G is! So, I don't know if I have been programming right. It's true that I have been lazy and I have reused a class to send the data which could be smaller. Could it be a big difference?  It has about 10 strings and 5 integers. It could be... 5? Really, I don't think that the object is too heavy. Another thing is that this object implements Serializable, I have read that there is another interface which I could implement and it's better if you're working with Android, but I'm working with Java as well, so I don't know if it's just when you're working with Android. I think that it's called `Parcelable`.

I'm trying to do something close to real time, and I'm waiting about 4-6 seconds from when I click the button to when the server returns the data.

When I press a button, the data is sent to the server using a socket. Server processes the information (pretty fast), and sends the updated data to this user and his opponent. On the Android side, I have created two `AsynTask`s. One is always listening to possible new data from the server and another one sends data to the server when the user does something.

The last problem is the difference in time between updating of different devices. I mean, the new data is coming 2 seconds early on one of these devices. Is it possible to synchronize this? I guess that it is because the difference quality of the network, so I guess that it could be hard. But, how could I improve this aspect?

UPDATED:

Well, I'm going to try a little of code, but, It's too much code!!

Okay,, What I think it's my first mistake is that the class I'm sending it's too big because I tried to reused the class to offline mode and online mode.

The class looks like:

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2849406755758020431L;
private List<Word> listWords;
private long numberWords;

private int score1; 
private int score2;

//OffLine
private int lifes;
private int numWordsNextLevel;
private int speedTime;
private int level;
private int difficult;

//Online
private String message;
private int numPlayers;
private int numWordsGame;
private String namePlayer1;
private String namePlayer2;


//Flags players
private boolean player1failed;
private boolean player2failed;
```

I think that I could reduce this to 4 ints and 2 Strings and a couple of booleans. Could it be a difference? is it worth it?

This is the class what I'm sending in both sides. Really, I don't need to send the same datas in both sides. So, the datas that I need to send to the server are pretty tiny.

About UDP or TCP, what happen when I lose a packet?? what do people usually do to improve it? How much faster is UDP than TCP? I know that you don't have to send the ACK,, but, I don't really know how much time is this part of the protocol.

I have been checking with DDMS how many datas I'm sending and it's about 1-1.5Kbytes each time,, I don't think that it's too much, I'm going to create an specific class to exchange the datas, but,, more advises about it?

Comment: This question is too vague to be answerable in its present form.  Can you make it more specific and show some of the code you are using to exchange data?

Comment: You should implement actual metrics using Android's svelt logging system. Log when you send the request for data and via what service, and when you receive the response. Note, too, that synchronizing between three nodes (two devices and your server) is likely going to involve a lot of blocking and latency, and thus not get the real-time feel you want. This is a vast topic: you should be specific about your current hurdle.

Comment: One tip is that you don't want to go with something like http as it uses TCP and is way too slow. Use UDP.

Comment: @MattWolfe problem with `UDP` is that you're not guaranteed that the packets will be received, as there are no acknowledge after packets are received - hence you could wait forever if the packet was lost...

Comment: you can fix this pretty easy, on client side set a timer, if it expires tell the server to resend.. use packet numbers to synchronize.

Comment: It depends though, if you do require reliable delivery for all packets then TCP is better. Usually games use UDP though.

Comment: Well, It's just a game to learn Android,, So, the idea it's a kind of trivial where more than one is playing,,, What it means, that you only update the data when someone does something. I mean, it doesn't make sense a timer in the client because you don't know when you're going to get new datas... you'll get more datas when another player does something. You're not getting datas each a period of time.